# Gitlab syntax highlighting fails although language is supported

Tags: gitlab, scilab, highlight.js

Gitlab uses `highlight.js` which supports the Scilab language, but it does not work as it can be seen in source tree files or snippets:

https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/blob/6.1/scilab/modules/cacsd/macros/abcd.sci

https://gitlab.com/mottelet/scilab/-/snippets/2424510

What is the problem ?